# Ruby on Rails 3 Time - Parse Milliseconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, milliseconds

I'm trying to parse a date like: 2011-05-21 04:20:46.011 into a Time object in Rails. So far I have the following:

```
Time.strptime("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N")
```

But it doesn't seem to like the "%3N" at the end. How do I parse this date?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `parse`:

```
x = Time.parse("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N")
# => 2011-05-21 04:20:46 -0700
x.usec
# => 11000
```

In many case you don't need to pass in the format either:

```
x = Time.parse("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011")
# => 2011-05-21 04:20:46 -0700
x.usec
# => 11000
```

Comment: Please refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41805509/936494 below for some intricate details about the behaviour of `parse` and `strptime` methods

Answer (score 3):

Try Time.parse("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N")

Comment: I think we answered at the same time :) It was just a matter of seconds I guess. But your answer is more informative. I have upvoated it.

Answer (score 3):

With **Ruby v 2.3.2** and **Rails v 5.0.0.1** in rails console

```
2.3.2 :035 > Time.parse("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N")
NoMethodError: undefined method `getlocal' for "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N":String
    from /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:264:in `make_time'
    from /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:366:in `parse'
    from (irb):35
```

*Note: In code below in the parse format, NOT prefixed `%N` with the number of fractional digits like `%3N` and instead simply specified `%N` and it works*

```
2.3.2 :037 > Time.strptime("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N")
 => 2011-05-21 04:20:46 +0530 
2.3.2 :038 > tt = Time.strptime("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N")
 => 2011-05-21 04:20:46 +0530 
2.3.2 :039 > tt.usec
 => 11000
```

The above code didn't worked when using `parse`

```
2.3.2 :040 > tt = Time.parse("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N")
NoMethodError: undefined method `getlocal' for "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N":String
    from /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:264:in `make_time'
    from /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:366:in `parse'
    from (irb):40
```

It looks strange because [Time.strptime(date, format, now=self.now)](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) official documentation does mention about `%3N`, `%6N` and `%9N` explicitly and using them in the parse format doesn't work!

Rails does provide a counterpart [strptime(str, format, now=now())](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-strptime) as part of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` API and it internally does the parsing using Ruby's standard `DateTime._strptime` as shown in its source-code:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb, line 382
def strptime(str, format, now=now())
  parts_to_time(DateTime._strptime(str, format), now)
end
```

And I guess [DateTime._strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) internally delegates to Ruby's standard [Time.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime)

For those who are looking for leveraging Rails's `Time.zone.parse` counterpart for parsing in a specific format they can use below code:

```
tt = Time.zone.strptime('1999-12-31 14:00:00.011111', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N')
 => Fri, 31 Dec 1999 14:00:00 UTC +00:00 
2.3.2 :031 > tt.usec
 => 11111
```

Hope someone from the core-team can clarify about this behaviour observed and if the behaviour is normal then at-least a note should be made about in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry @m1keil I didn't pursued it afterwards. And it has been more than a year I posted this answer and hence unable to recollect the context for which I tried the posted code in my answer.